# Calling a private function of a module from a public method

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor code tries to call the `send` function but the server reports error "send is not defined" and if I change the culprit line to `request.send`, I get Object has no method send.

Why and how to fix it? Thanks

```
request = (function () {
  const paths = {logout: {method: 'GET'}}
  const send = () => {some code}

  return {
   registerRequestAction: (path, func) => {
      paths[path].action = func;
   },
   invoke: (type) => {
     paths[type].action();
   }       
  }

  }());

request.registerRequestAction('logout', () => {
 send();  // send is not defined
 request.send();  // object has no method send

});

request.invoke('logout');  // to fire it up
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous object without reference to the send method:

```
  // this isn't visible from the outside
  const send = () => {some code} 

  // this is visible from the outside,
  // but with no reference to send()
  return {
   registerRequestAction: (path, func) => {
      paths[path].action = func;
   },
   invoke: (type) => {
     paths[type].action();
   }       
  }
```

Doing something like this should fix your issue:

```
return {
    registerRequestAction: (path, func) => {
          paths[path].action = func;
    },
    invoke: (type) => {
         paths[type].action();
    },
    // expose send to the outside
    send: send
}

request.registerRequestAction('logout', () => {
    request.send();
});
```